# Binary to text encoding on Array

Tags: encoding, character-encoding, binary, urlencode, url-encoding

I have an array of integers:

```
arr = [83,107,57,74,84,103,61,61];
```

I need to pass it through a function to get a message (string).

```
String msg = f(arr);
```

It's only given that f is a binary-to-text encoding function.

How do I get the string. I tried searching a lot on the net. Even took the char taking the values as ascii but it didn't work. 61 gives '=' which can't come in the message.
Could any of you please help?

Comment: what language are you using????????

Comment: Its not language dependent. Anything that gives me the url will work. Be it Python, JS, Ruby, C++, C etc.

Comment: but you are asking, `how`...

Comment: I'm asking the method to be used. The function algo that's to be used. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in C#

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] nx = StringToIntArray(IntArrayToString(new int[] { 1, 2, 3 }));

        foreach (int n in nx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(n);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static string IntArrayToString(int[] nx)
    {
        byte[] bx = new byte[nx.Length * 4];

        for (int i = 0; i < nx.Length; i++)
        {
            BitConverter.GetBytes(nx[i]).CopyTo(bx, i * 4);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(bx);
    }

    static int[] StringToIntArray(string str)
    {
        byte[] bx = Convert.FromBase64String(str);

        int len = bx.Length / 4;

        int[] nx = new int[len];

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
        {
            nx[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(bx, i * 4);
        }

        return nx;
    }
}
```